# Como enviar comandos do teclado para emulador?

Tags: python, jogos

Eai Galera, eu estou tentando fazer um programa pra fazer um combo automático num jogo de luta (The King of Fighters 2002) , já tentei usar bibliotecas como pyautogui, keyboard, ctypes e etc, mas não consigo fazer o programa apertar as teclas pra andar automaticamente no emulador (Fightcade), alguém sabe me dizer como resolver? segue o que tenho de código até agora:

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard
import time

def Combo1():
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
            pyautogui.keyDown('left')
            time.sleep(0.1)
            pyautogui.keyUp('left')

Combo1()
```

o de baixo está usando uma api do windows pra fazer os comandos com direct keys...

```
import ctypes
import keyboard
from ctypes import wintypes
import time

user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)

INPUT_MOUSE    = 0
INPUT_KEYBOARD = 1
INPUT_HARDWARE = 2

KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001
KEYEVENTF_KEYUP       = 0x0002
KEYEVENTF_UNICODE     = 0x0004
KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE    = 0x0008

MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC = 0

# msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731

Z = 0x2C
X = 0x2D
C = 0x2E
V = 0x2F

LEFT = 0xCB
RIGHT = 0xCD
UP = 0xC8
DOWN = 0xD0

# C struct definitions

SendInput = ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput

# C struct redefinitions 
PUL = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong)
class KeyBdInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("wVk", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("wScan", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("time", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]

class HardwareInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("uMsg", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("wParamL", ctypes.c_short),
                ("wParamH", ctypes.c_ushort)]

class MouseInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("dx", ctypes.c_long),
                ("dy", ctypes.c_long),
                ("mouseData", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("time",ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]

class Input_I(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [("ki", KeyBdInput),
                 ("mi", MouseInput),
                 ("hi", HardwareInput)]

class Input(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("type", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("ii", Input_I)]
# Functions
def PressKey(hexKeyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

def ReleaseKey(hexKeyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008 | 0x0002, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

def Combo1():
    flag = True
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
            while flag: 
                PressKey(DOWN) # 
                time.sleep(0.1)
                ReleaseKey(DOWN) #
                if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
                    flag = False
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Combo1()
```

Comment: Vai depender mesmo de como o emulador interfaceia com o hardware - deixe um link pro emulador aí - também avalie se você consegue jogar o mesmo jogo em outro emulador.

Comment: eu estou tentando usar o cheat engine pra entender os endereços de memória responsaveis por input no jogo pra depois fazer um script pra alterar esses endereços de memoria da forma que eu quiser, mas tá parecendo mais complicado do que eu pensei que seria, queria realmente fazer dessa forma mais fácil com python, vou deixar o link do fightcade aqui se quiser dar uma olhada: https://www.fightcade.com/

Comment: se for  um emulador de uma máquina mai antiga (16 bit, ou com cartucho) e o seu emulador tiver uma opção de salvar um "snapshot" - isso é - toda a memória da máquina em um único arquivo - uma "foto" do estado do jogo - é mais ou menos tranquilo fazer o que você quer - mas isso não tem nada a ver com enviar uma sequencia de teclas para o emulador rodando.

Comment: O que eu quero fazer com o Cheat Engine é achar as posições de memória responsáveis por controlar os comandos do jogo, creio que deva ser um binário 0 ou 1 pra dizer se a tecla foi apertada ou algo assim, depois disso, se eu fizesse um script que conseguisse alterar esses valores e fazer os comandos no jogo em uma certa ordem, eu conseguiria fazer combos automáticos.

Comment: isso já não é tão simples - a tecla pressionada pode nem ir pra memoria, dependendo do hardware - a CPU verifica se uma tcla está pressionada e chama uma rotina direto pra iniciar um movimento - o estado que diz que o movimento está sendo executado é a posição do programa, e não uma variável na memória. Esse tipo de cheat funciona pra aumentar o número de vidas, maximizar o HP, etc..

Answer (score -1):

Procure uma ferramenta que chama [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). Ela te permite escrever scripts para capturar inputs no teclado ou mouse e rodar ações automaticamente. Você pode escrever um script dizendo quais comandos vão ser enviados quando você apertar determinada tecla. A linguagem para escrever os scripts é super simples e você pode ativar/desativar cada script quando for usar.

Como exemplo, veja um script que escrevi para substituir a combinação de teclas CTRL + Alt Gr por uma seta à direita quando estiver na janela do Spyder:

```
#IfWinActive Spyder (Python 3.8)
LControl & RAlt::
Send, {Right}
return
```